# Getting arrayindexoutofboundException inside getView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to android.This is the code where i am getting exception mentioned below inside getView(). I am trying to list music titlename along with music duration which when clicked starts playing music.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Cursor c;
    int index;
    int count;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    private ArrayList<String> mnamedata = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mdurationdata = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView mname;
        TextView mduration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String cols[] = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };

        try {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            c = contentResolver.query(uri, cols, null, null, null);

            count = c.getCount();
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lv.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
            mp = new MediaPlayer();

            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                mnamedata.add(c.getString(0));
                mdurationdata.add(c.getString(1));
            }

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    c.moveToPosition(arg2);
                    String fn = c.getString(2);
                    try {
                        if (mp.isPlaying())
                            mp.reset();
                        mp.setDataSource(fn);
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No sdcard presents");
        }

    }

    private class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context music_context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        private MusicAdapter(Context c) {
            music_context = c;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) music_context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listinflate, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.mname = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.mname);
            holder.mduration = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.mduration);
            holder.mname.setText(mnamedata.get(position));
            holder.mduration.setText(mdurationdata.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**listinflate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="6pt"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mduration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Code"
        android:textSize="6pt" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**

```
 04-29 01:02:38.455: E/AndroidRuntime(17156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 01:02:38.455: E/AndroidRuntime(17156): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
04-29 01:02:38.455: E/AndroidRuntime(17156):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
04-29 01:02:38.455: E/AndroidRuntime(17156):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
04-29 01:02:38.455: E/AndroidRuntime(17156):    at com.example.musiclistview.MainActivity$MusicAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:132)
04-29 01:02:38.455: E/AndroidRuntime(17156):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2603)
04-29 01:02:38.455: E/AndroidRuntime(17156):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1253)
```

Comment: Can you post the full output of logcat?

Comment: After this line `c = contentResolver.query(uri, cols, null, null, null);` you have to do `c.moveToFirst();` because you are actually pointed BEFORE the first record.

Comment: @BobMalooga same music title and duration is repeating in entire listview

Comment: You forgot to `c.moveToNext();` in your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to add c.moveToFirst() in order to ensure the cursor is in the first position before the for and add c.moveToNext() in order to move the cursor to the next position also you can change your for for a while(!c.isAfterLast()){} to move through the cursor

```
...

count = c.getCount();
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
mp = new MediaPlayer();
c.moveToFirst();
for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
...
c.moveToNext();
}

...
```